# C# webBrowser HTMLDoc.Click fires more then once, why?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, webbrowser-control, dom

I have the code below but when I click on the web page it fires 2 - 6 times. How can I make it just fire once?

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
   {
      htmlDoc = webBrowser1.Document;
      htmlDoc.Click += htmlDoc_Click;
      //htmlDoc.MouseDown += htmlDoc_MouseDown;
      //htmlDoc.MouseMove += htmlDoc_MouseMove;
      htmlDoc.ContextMenuShowing += htmlDoc_ContextMenuShowing;
   }
}

void htmlDoc_Click(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Mouse Click");
   if (e.CtrlKeyPressed)
   {
      if (webBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition).InnerHtml != null)
      {
        //MessageBox.Show(webBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(webBrowser1.PointToClient(MousePosition)).InnerText.ToString());
        Debug.WriteLine(webBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition).InnerHtml);
      }

      e.ReturnValue = false;
      return;
   }

   // stop mouse events moving on to the HTML doc return false
   e.ReturnValue = true;
}
```

Comment: You do realize every time a document loads you will register for the click event...thus potentially creating what you are describing.

Comment: is your page being loaded into the WebBrowser control sitting on the form?

Comment: @ Max yes it is.

@Aaron thanks I think you are correct, but I'm not sure how to make it only add the event handler on the last documentComplete?

Comment: Have you tried overriding the Dispose before inheriting your own wrapper from WebBrower class? I posted in the answer what you need to do to stop this from happening. WebBrowser is an Active X control under the hood so you should do some clean up associated with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the web page you visit contains frames then the DocumentCompleted event will fire multiple times, once for each frame.  And thus you'll subscribe the event multiple times.  Filter this by checking e.Url.Equals(webBrowser1.Url), it is only true for the last one.

Another problem you'll have to solve is unsubscribing the event, right now you'll leak the HtmlDocument.  Be sure to unsubscribe before calling Navigate().

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own Dispose method and unsubscribe there from all the events:

```
            htmlDoc.Click -= htmlDoc_Click;

            htmlDoc.ContextMenuShowing -= htmlDoc_ContextMenuShowing;
```

Loos like your variables are global so should not be an issue.